# drupal not detecting function in custom module's inc file

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a custom module, in my module call `commerce_discount_add_line_item()` function, it exists in `commerce_discount.rules.inc`, 
this modules is installed correctly and status is enabled but when I call it returns:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   commerce_discount_add_line_item().

It is strange, why has this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default inc files are not included(only module files are included). They should be called explicitly like below before making a call to a function in that file.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'commerce_discount', 'commerce_discount.rules');
```

Further Reading on inc files and how they differ from .module files : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54069/4876

Comment: tnx , I tried this, but want to know why. tnx.

Comment: You are faster than me.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have included `commerce_discount.rules.inc` file in your module file.

You can use below code to include file, if you have not included files into your module file.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'commerce_discount', 'commerce_discount.rules');
```